# Do I have to add Microsoft.Bcl.Async to my InstallShield project?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, installshield, base-class-library

I'm developing a library with .NET Framework 4.0, C# and Visual Studio 2012.

On this library I use Nuget package Microsoft.Bcl.Async. This is my packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

Now, I'm adding this project to an existing InstallShield project that will install all my dlls on GAC (I have more libraries projects).

My question is: what do I have to add to this InstallShield project?

I'm asking this because Microsoft.Bcl.Async uses System.Runtime.dll, System.Threading.Tasks.dll and System.IO.dll. I'm not user if I have to add these libraries to my InstallShield project or it will be conflicts on the installation computer.

Comment: The point of the GAC is that you can have multiple assemblies with the same name but thanks to strong names and versioning you won't have conflicts.

Comment: Install whatever you find back in your project's bin\Release folder.